# Why am I getting “Permission denied” while trying to create a file

Tags: linux, file-permissions

```
jenkins@hostname:~/dir1/dir2$ ls -ld /some-nfs
drwxrwxrwx 121 171 146 6290 Feb  8 15:38 /some-nfs

jenkins@hostname:~/dir1/dir2$ ls -ld /some-nfs/important-dir
drwxrwxrwx 3 jenkins jenkins 28 Feb  8 15:39 /some-nfs/important-dir

jenkins@hostname:~/dir1/dir2$ mkdir /some-nfs/important-dir/important-dir/logs # able to create a dir

jenkins@hostname:~/dir1/dir2$ ls -ld /some-nfs/important-dir/logs
drwxrwxr-x 2 jenkins jenkins 0 Feb  8 15:39 /some-nfs/important-dir/logs

jenkins@hostname:~/dir1/dir2$ touch /some-nfs/important-dir/logs/file # not able to create a file
touch: cannot touch ‘/some-nfs/important-dir/logs/file’: Permission denied
```

Why am I getting **Permission denied** in the last step ?

I was expecting to be able to create the file.

Comment: Where is here? Is this an NFS mount from somewhere else? If so, are you synchronizing user IDs manually, or with NIS or LDAP?

Comment: /some-nfs is an nfs mount. I am not synchronizing my user ids. jenkins user is not an ldap user. It exists on the machine because I have jenkins installed on the machine.

Comment: So is the user ID for jenkins on this example machine the same as the ID for jenkins on the NFS server?

Comment: jenkins does not exist on the nfs server.

Comment: But please note I am able to create a directory using `mkdir` but not able to create a file using `touch`

Comment: Can you show your /etc/fstab please?

Comment: `a.b.c.com:/some-name     /some-nfs nfs rw 0 0` fstab entry

Answer (score 1):

NFS by default will downgrade any files created with the root permissions to the nobody:nogroup user:group.

This is a security feature that prevents privileges from being shared unless specifically requested.

It may be that you would like to enable the "no_root_squash" option in the nfs server's /etc/exports file.

There is [a really nice article](http://fullyautolinux.blogspot.co.il/2015/11/nfs-norootsquash-and-suid-basic-nfs.html) about root_squash that I recommend you to read before deciding if it's the correct solution for you.

Comment: I do not have access to server's /etc/exports  file and there is no way I can get that access. Even if I did get access I will not be allowed to change the /etc/exports file.

Comment: Then I don't think you'll be able to solve it.